# How to update JoinTable in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two classes `Student` and `Subject`:

**Student**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "full_name")
private String fullName;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "students")
private Set<Subject> subject;

//Getters & setters
}
```

**Subject**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "subjects")
public class Subject {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "subject_name")
private String name;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Student> students;
//Getters & setters
}
```

When I am trying to save a student registered with more than one subject, I am not getting any records in the JoinTable.

My code for saving the entiers:

```
    Subject subject = new Subject();
    subject.setName("JAVA");

    Subject subject2 = new Subject();
    subject2.setName("C");

    Subject subject3 = new Subject();
    subject3.setName("C++");

    Student student = new Student();
    student.setFullName("dibya");

    Set<Subject> subjects = new HashSet<>();
    subjects.add(subject2);
    subjects.add(subject);
    subjects.add(subject3);

    student.setSubject(subjects);

    session.saveOrUpdate(student);
```

Please tell me where am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem.

It was not with the configuration. With just `mappedBy` attribute `ManyToMany` relationship can be accomplished.

In my program I have added `session.saveOrUpdate(subject);` after saving saving the students.

This solved my problem. :)

Comment: If you do the right mapping you could avoid the `session.saveOrUpdate(subject);`

Answer (score 0):

A many-to-many relationship is modeled as a join table. This is a table with 2 columns, both are foreign keys to the tables of the repationship (*Student* and *Subject* in your case).

In Hibernate if you use `@ManyToMany` you need to either `@JoinTable` or `@JoinColumn` to define the relationship. Once it's done your update will work.

See

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html

and

http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-many-using-annotations-1.html

**EDIT:**
Applied to your code it should look like (UNTESTED):

**In Student:**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "student_id")
private int id;
....
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "students_subject", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "student_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id") })
    private Set<Subject> subject;
```

**In Subject**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "subject_id")
private int id;
...
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "students_subject", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "student_id") })
private Set<Student> students;
```

Comment: Could you please post a solution for this? I tried using a JoinTable. It creates two tables : `students_subjects` and `subjects_students`. With empty records;

Comment: No. Still Not working. No error is thrown but link table is not getting updated.

Comment: Has the table `students_subject` been generated?

Comment: you can try a `session.flush()` at the end too

Answer (score 0):

Your case might be falling into mixing JPA and Hibernate cascading. Try annotate your `@ManyToMany` with additional

```
@Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
```

you can also consult this two links to check if this is really your case:

- [Confusion between JPA and Hibernate cascading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540806/confusion-between-jpa-and-hibernate-cascadingist)
- http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/cascade-jpa-hibernate-annotation-common-mistake/